# Transition multiple EC2 instances from IMDSv1 to IMDSv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata, auto

Is there a way to update 100s of EC2 instances on one account without having to use [modify-instance-metadata-options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-metadata-options.html) with --instance-id on every single instance?

I've looked around thinking surely I'm not the only one with this problem can't find much. I was toying with the idea of writing an ansible playbook, but that might be overthinking things.

Comment: Get a list of the EC2 instance in question, wrap it in a loop and perform the necessary API call, that is a few lines of python.

Comment: If you use Auto Scaling Groups, don't forget to modify those too. Good document on the process [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html#instance-metadata-transition-to-version-2) (which you're probably already aware of, but I'm sharing for others).

Comment: You could also use Systems Manager Automation. Haven't done this, but there's an AWS runbook to upgrade metadata usage - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager-automation-runbooks/latest/userguide/automation-awssupport-configureec2metadata.html - and you can apply runbooks to multiple instances at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The following will be helpful if you can progressively relaunch EC2 using the source AMI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-IMDS-new-instances.html

Run the following from a place where you can run AWS commands against your AMI

`aws ec2 modify-image-attribute \ --image-id ami-0123456789example \ --imds-support v2.0`

Any EC2 instances launched using the above AMI will have IMDSV1 disabled and IMDSV2 enabled.

I hope this helps,
Thanks